# Pip Error : 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, openssl, pip

I tried to install from pip and keep on getting similar type of errors.

```
$ pip install quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

Now even though i tried to install different pip modules iam getting same error.Is there any solution for this ? This was caused due to the unexpected killing of the process while a pip module is being downloaded.

Please help me with the necessary steps to rectify this error.

I tried to install this

```
$ pip install -U cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

Comment: You should try : pip install -U cryptography

Comment: Same error even to get cryptography installed.

Comment: It seems that something related to SSL is missing. You probably should upgrade your pip (never know) : pip install --upgrade pip and then try to pip OpenSSL with : pip install pyOpenSSL

Comment: @FlorianJOUFFREAU even to upgrade pip it is showing same error.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install python-pip to install pip then try to install modules

Comment: uninstall pip and reinstall it. `sudo apt-get purge python-pip`

Comment: @VikashSingh did a clean uninstall and installed it and as soon as i entered `pip` it gave the long error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04.3 here:

I think I have fixed this by removing the python-openssl package (and it's dependencies) with:

```
apt-get --auto-remove remove python-openssl
```

Then installing the latest version with pip:

```
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Of course, if you install another apt package that depends on it, it'll pull it back in. I hope if you use pip for everything you can from now on instead of apt, it should be fine.

Edit: as of January 2019 this issue doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to do ```pip install pyopenssl```.

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 16.04.3 : `apt-get --auto-remove --yes remove python-openssl` removes a lot of dependencies packages ! including `landscape-common`, `python-qt4` and `oneconf`. I had to reinstall them after issuing this command : `apt install landscape-common python-qt4 oneconf` and then finally `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: @M-Jack Perhaps it's better to not use --auto-remove then?

Comment: Not sure... I have tried only your solution. But it is probably important to reinstall then the packages that have been removed.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to tell people to run a command that removes a package which *many* other packages depend on, especially with flags that auto-confirm! This ended up removing over 700 packages from my system...

Comment: Due to feedback I've changed my answer to ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the openssl python lib and reinstalling (purge before install did not work):

```sh
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/
$ sudo apt install --reinstall python-openssl
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately. Brings back the same error after reinstalling. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: @AsfandQazi you should confirm that's the python you're using and the potential location for other methods of installation for the lib. `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` will let you know where to look.

Answer (score 4):

If even pip is not working then try following:

```
sudo easy_install -U cffi
sudo easy_install -U cryptography
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it on RHEL/CentOS:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/
sudo yum install pyOpenSSL
```

This did it for me on CentOS 7. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error and solved it by doing these steps (**don't forget to put your own username**):

```
rm -rf /home/<Your Username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL
sudo rm -rf usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the following:

```
$ rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL
$ rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.15.1.egg-info
```

In the last line, you might have another version of `pyOpenSSL`, specify yours.

Comment: I needed to delete it from both directories /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib then reinstalling cryptography==2.6.1 and pyopenssl==19.0.0 on ubuntu 20.04. I installed it using pip3.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Fix**

Move the OpenSSL folder to OpenSSLBAK (for instance) to avoid the error

```
# cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
# mv OpenSSL OpenSSLBAK
```

It should be good

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling python of which will fix many of your problems,do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

and pip will be missing after reinstalling,do

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: how many `pip` directory do you have at `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`??

Comment: Anyway,go to the path i mentioned above,,delete manual any pip directory you find then do `python get-pip.py` again

Answer (score -1):

Try to download the suitable wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quantlib) depending in your operating system and python version. Then add this file to Python/Scripts and use the code below to install it.

```
pip install nameofwheelfile.whl
```

The wheel file contains all the dependencies.

Comment: Problem is not only for a specific module,i can do this method.But real problem is it is not working for any module.Even i enter `pip` it produces the same results.

Comment: OK. If you try as a sudo user do you get the same error as well?

Comment: YES same result

Comment: Hm.. Did you try to `upgrade pip`?

Comment: That link is for windows python libs, the question is tagged with `linux` and `ubuntu` so that won't help much.